# Crashpad_Handler using +100% CPU

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu

First of all but not my main question how can something use the CPU for more than 100%?

My main question is how can I get rid of it? Is it safe to force it to stop? I think it's a Google Chrome thing, from what I could gather. It uses up a lot of CPU leading to my laptop heating up and fast battery drain.

Has anyone a solution to this problem?
[image]

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) with Sierra (10.12.6)

Edit: I usually use Safari and do not have Chrome installed only firefox as a second browser.

Comment: CPU percentage is by maximum simultaneous threads. Older processors could only do one thread per core, so the max for a dual core processor would be 200%. Newer Intel processors support “hyperthreading”, which means it can run two threads per core. So processors like this (any Intel i5/i7/Xeon processor newer than about 2010) have maximums of 200% per physical core. So a newer dual-core processor maxes out at 400%, a newer quad-core processor maxes out at 800%, and my dual hex-core Mac Pro maxes out at 2400% (2 processors x 6 cores x 2 threads).

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.